Why is Gradle throwing a "transport error 202" when running bootRun from intellij works from terminal
Info
Windows w/ WSL
Java 23, Gradle 8.10, Spring Boot Gradle Plugin 3.3.4
Issue
When I run ./gradlew clean bootRun from the terminal everything works. However, when I try the same thing from Intellij I get
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.For more details on the daemon, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html in the Gradle documentation.
Process command line: /home/jgleason/lib/java/jdk-23/bin/java --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=384m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=172.18.176.1:53111 --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/jgleason/lib/gradle/gradle-8.10.2/lib/gradle-daemon-main-8.10.2.jar -javaagent:/home/jgleason/lib/gradle/gradle-8.10.2/lib/agents/gradle-instrumentation-agent-8.10.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 8.10.2
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [open/src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:700]


How would I get this to run from IJ as well?
I also tried this but it didn't solve it
Gradle / IntelliJ miscommunication causing "Unable to start daemon process"

Looks to be a bug in IJ link here. I confirmed that using run did work it was just debug.
